# Is the np.clip redundant for the min-max normalization

Tags: python, numpy, math

What's the `range` of the default `min-max normalization`? Is it `[0, 1]` or `[−1, 1]` or `both`? How to get the range of `[-1,1]`?

```
X_scaled = (X - X_min)/(X_max - X_min)
```

And the numpy `clip`:

```
X_scaled_clipped = np.clip((X - X_min)/(X_max - X_min), 0, 1)
```

Is the `np.clip(..., 0, 1)` redundant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This transformation:

```
def minmax_xform(x):
    x_max = np.amax(x)
    x_min = np.amin(x)
    return (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
```

Gives you values in the `[0, 1]` range.

To get to the `[-1, 1]` range, just multiply by `2` (the size of the new range -- the new maximum minus the new minimum) and add `-1` (the new minimum):

```py
def minmax_xform(x, max_=1, min_=-1):
    x_max = np.amax(x)
    x_min = np.amin(x)
    size = (max_ - min_)
    return size * (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min) + min_
```

The clipping would be redundant.

Note that all this assumes no `NaN`s or `inf`s, which should be addressed separately.